# Code Review for simple column summary function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I'm working through *R for Data Science* and the question I'm working on is asking to adapt an already made function to only numeric columns.

The original function is the following:

```
   out <- vector("double", length(df))
   for (i in seq_along(df)) {
        out[i] <- fun(df[[i]])
       
        out[i] = "Not Numeric"
     }
   out
}
```

The adapted function is the following:

```
    out <- vector("double", length(df))
    for (i in seq_along(df)) {
        if (is.numeric(df[[i]] == TRUE)){
        out[i] <- fun(df[[i]])
        } else{
            out[i] = "Not Numeric"
        }
    }
    out
}
```

And I was doing the testing on the following data frame:

```
    a = rnorm(10),
    b = rnorm(10),
    c = rnorm(10),
    d = letters[1:10],
    e = LETTERS[11:20],
    f = runif(10)
)
```

So the way the function is supposed to work is that say I wanted to calculate the means of the columns. Then I would proceed to enter: `col_summary(df,mean)` and the output should be:
`mean_1 mean_2 mean_3 "Not Numeric" "Not Numeric" mean_4`

Instead I'm just getting a vector of "Not Numerics". So the question is what did I do wrong in my attempt. I don't see anything wrong, but I guess that's why I'm here now.

Comment: What is `fun()` here.  Your condition should be `if(is.numeric(df[[i]]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
df[[i]] == TRUE
```

wouldn't work as expected because it is testing for each value of the columns to be TRUE and `if/else` expects a single TRUE/FALSE as input instead of a logical vector of length > 1.  it would be

```
if(is.numeric(df[[i]]))
```

Comment: THat did the job. Thanks for the help